# how to copy html code to clipboard using zeroclip?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zclip

I'm trying to create a button that will copy html code to the clipboard using zclip.

this is the code I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                jQuery('button#copy_code').zclip({
                      path:'<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
                              copy: '
<h1 style="text-align: center;">
<strong>
How to Make A Website in 10 Minutes with Arvixe
</strong>
</h1>
<br>
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9_grBUEtxPY?iv_load_policy=3&vq=large&rel=0&modestbranding=1&autoplay=0&ampcontrols=0;showinfo=0" height="325" width="580" frameborder="0"></iframe></p>'
                            });
                        })
                    </script>
                </div>
<br>
<button id="copy_code" type="button" class="copylink_b">
</button>
```

However, it's not working. The button won't do anything. This button will work when using plain text, but will not when trying to copy html. How can I copy html using zclip?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have a multiline string in javascript without ending each line with `\`

You should have seen an error in the console.

Comment: of course you can, but you must declare it as a variable

Comment: No.. Even if you declare it as a variable you cannot have a multiline string as a variable in javascript. Try it, you will get a javascript error.

Comment: `var multiline = "line"+"\n"+"line"."\n"+..` etc

Comment: @davidkonrad that is **multiple** strings concatenated.

Comment: Yes, and the result is ...? OP should just implement it this way

Comment: Ok thank you qwrtynl. Is there a simple way to make it work then or is copying html code to the zeroclipboard impossible?